# Sapreste dirmi perché alcuni dicono "mi dai il tiro" quando chiedono che il portone di un edificio sia aperto?

Tags: idioms, regional

Quando soggiorno in Emilia-Romagna sento spesso dire "mi dai il tiro".

Considerato che ciò accade quando qualcuno chiede a qualcun altro di aprire il portone di un edificio, sapreste dirmi qual è l'origine di quest'espressione e se essa viene compresa anche al di fuori dell'ambito regionale che ho indicato?

Comment: Non ho mai sentito questa espressione prima d'ora, quindi è probabile che sia dialettale. "Dammi un tiro" o "Fammi fare un tiro" è invece generalmente usata (in tutta Italia?) per chiedere a qualcuno di dare una boccata ad una sigaretta.

Comment: Grazie @nico, ma li dove l'ho sentita dire significa "apri il portone".

Comment: "Dammi un tiro" significa anche "dammi un passaggio" nel Nordest.

Answer (score 15):

Questa è un'espressione tipicamente bolognese. A Bologna città ricca di portici, le case erano al primo piano, mentre al pian terreno c'erano i portoni che permettevano l'ingresso nei cortili interni dei palazzi. I portoni erano collegati con una corda agli appartamenti.

Così quando un ospite arrivava e voleva entrare chiedeva che qualcuno dal di dentro desse un tiro alla corda.

In molti palazzi di Bologna e d'intorni all'interno del portone, invece dei classici pulsanti Luce e Porta, per accendere le luci nelle scale e aprire il portono, ci sono i pulsanti Luce e, appunto, Tiro.

Answer (score 2):

È un'espressione piuttosto strana che personalmente non ho mai sentito. 
Ho appena chiesto al miei coinquilini, uno emiliano di Reggio e uno romagnolo di Rimini, e nemmeno loro dicono di averla mai sentita, quindi posso supporre che abbia una diffusione piuttosto limitata. A giudicare dai commenti, pare in uso soltanto nella zona di Bologna.

Detto questo posso provare a supporre che si riferisca al gesto fisico di aprire la porta. I portoni degli edifici spesso si richiudono da soli, quindi uno strattone (un "tiro") dato alla porta può consentire ad un altro di passare, lasciando poi chiudere la porta alle sue spalle.

Francamente ho l'impressione che sia un'espressione molto molto localizzata. Pur essendo madrelingua, se qualcuno si riferisse a me chiedendomi di "dare il tiro" penserei di aver capito male e chiederei delucidazioni.

Comment: Chissà se nei portoni antichi c'erano delle corde che era necessario tirare per aprire i portoni, oppure se, all'atto dell'apertura, chi era dentro doveva tirare un po' il portone affinchè si aprisse.

Comment: Comunque, sicuramente a Bologna questa espressione è in uso. Infatti i portalettere, dopo aver citofonato a qualche inquilino, dicono "tiro", come per dire "apri".

Comment: Comunqe, ancora, +1 per aver proposto una spiegazione sensata, oltreché ben ragionata.

Comment: Ho aggiornato la mia risposta dopo aver chiesto al mio altro coinquilino romagnolo. A Reggio Emilia e Rimini mai sentita, probabilmente è in uso solo a Bologna. Secondo me, ripeto, è semplicemente un uso dovuto all'atto fisico di tirare la porta e non ha motivazioni storiche, ma sono aperto a spiegazioni alternative